# Position Material UI popover when clicked on icon

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, popover

I have to make the popover like below. When clicked on the icon the popover should open with exactly the same UI.
[image]

Below is the code I am using

```
{showPopOver && (
              <Popover
                open={showPopOver}
                onClose={(e) => {
                  if (showPopOver) {
                    e.stopPropagation()
                    toggleModal()
                  }
                }}
                anchorEl={imageRef?.current}
                anchorOrigin={{
                  vertical: `top`,
                  horizontal: `center`,
                }}
                transformOrigin={{
                  vertical: `top`,
                  horizontal: `center`,
                }}
                PaperProps={{
                  style: { width: "400px", height: "300px" },
                }}
              ><POPOVER CONTENTS........>


</popover>
)}
```

I am getting the popover but it overlaps the icon

Could anyone please let me know how can I place the popover above the icon with the v(callout)

any input to resolve this issue would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try adding `marginBottom` to `PaperProps` styles?

Comment: @HamedSiaban Position is set to absolute(since I am using image ref) so margin wont work.I tried overriding with position relative but still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform the origin of <Popover .> by adding transformOrigin to its property. Like so:

```
transformOrigin={{ horizontal: "left", vertical: -20 }}
```